# Запись в таблицу с другой таблицы

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Нужно записать данные в таблицу с другой таблицы. Пробовал так, но получаю ошибку `SQL error: near "SELECT": syntax error`. Первый аргумент `SELECT` это калонка другой таблицы а второй аргумент это название самой таблицы.

```
"INSERT INTO '%q' "
            "('%q'"
            ",'%q'"
            ",'%q'"
            ...)"
        "VALUES ("
            " SELECT '%q' FROM '%q'"
            ",SELECT '%q' FROM '%q'"
            ",'%q'"
            ",'%q'
             ...)"
```

Comment: `insert into table(...) seleсt ... from ...`

Comment: @Mike, не могу понять, поясните немного подробнее

Comment: Ну values используется когда вы хотите занести конкретные значения. А когда надо вставить одну или несколько строк на основе выборки из других таблиц(ы) используется предложение select вместо values

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 (field1_1, field1_2, ...) SELECT field2_1, 'literal2_2', ... FROM table2`

Comment: @Mike, а если я хочу что бы только две строки заносились с другой таблицы а остальные будут конкретными значениями?

Comment: Что значит "только две строки", не путайте пожалуйста строки с колонками. Будет занесено столько строк, сколько вернет ваш select (его предварительно надо протестировать, что бы возвращал то, что нужно). А что касается колонок, конечно select может возвращать константные значения в любых колонках, как написал в примере выше @Akina `'literal2_2'` это константа, она берется не из таблицы, а как есть

Comment: @Mike, не совсем понял за 'literal2_2'.

Comment: @UjinUkr Ну это конкретное значение, а не название колонки таблицы, `select 1,2,3,column from tableX` вернет строки с 4 колонками с одержимым 1,2,3 и содержимым колонки column. А количество строк будет равно количеству строк в таблице. Вы не спрашивайте, вы пробуйте. 95% всех знаний по SQL я получал экспериментальным путем

Comment: @Mike, последний вопрос, как заставить SELECT вернуть только последнюю запись с калонки. Попробовал так: SELECT MAX('%q') FROM '%q' но возвращается имя калонки

Comment: А зачем вы в кавычки имя то заключаете ?

Comment: @Mike, спасибо огромное)